# How to crop center part of large image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

When a image is cropped from the center then crop image will take the aspect ratio of source image,But According to my requirement, aspect ratio will be change with new crop size.

I want to get exact center part of image with new aspect ratio.For example a large image is of size (320*480) then I want to crop center part of image of size (100,100) and aspect ratio will also be 100*100 ,No outer white or black part is required and image quality will be high.

Cropping function :

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*)image andFrame:(CGRect)rect {

    //Note : rec is nothing but the image frame which u want to crop exactly.

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*image.scale,
                      rect.origin.y*image.scale,
                      rect.size.width*image.scale,
                      rect.size.height*image.scale);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                                          scale:image.scale
                                    orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Leave Xcode tag alone. The question is not related to Xcode IDE at all. And, where is your code ?

Comment: I have update my question with cropping function

Comment: any one help me ... my project try to face shape image crop but not crop  for objective c

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might run

```
- (UIImage *)imageByCroppingImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    // not equivalent to image.size (which depends on the imageOrientation)!
    double refWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    double refHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);

    double x = (refWidth - size.width) / 2.0;
    double y = (refHeight - size.height) / 2.0;

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(x, y, size.height, size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.0 orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropped;
}
```

Comment: how to posible to image center part slim like curve shape any  one know this concept  so  please   guys let me know

Answer (score 1):

#### Calculate crop rect from image

```
float imgHeight = 100.0f; //Any according to requirement
float imgWidth = 100.0f; //Any according to requirement
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake((largeImage.size.width/2)-(imgWidth/2),largeImage.size.height/2)-(imgHeight/2),imgWidth,imgHeight);
```

#### Now crop it

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
// or use the UIImage wherever you like
UIImage *croppedImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ,I have already try above code ,But it just crop the image but aspect ratio still as source image.

Comment: Price, I have implement your code ,but whole image is created with white color .
in my case large image size is 320*320.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageView = UIImageView()

// height and width values corresponds to rectangle height and width

imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height ))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Your Image Name")

// by   setting   content  mode  to  .ScaleAspectFill   image centrally  fill  in   imageView. image   might appear beyond  image frame.

imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill


// by   setting .clipsToBouds to true,  image set to image frame.

imageView.clipsToBounds = true
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, when you answer please provide a short explanation, and format your code (four spaces will work)

Answer (score 1):

// Work this code

```
     -(UIImage *)croppedImage
    {
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self.bezierPath closePath];
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    _b_image = self.bg_imageview.image;
    CGSize imageSize = _b_image.size;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [self.bezierPath addClip];
    [_b_image drawInRect:imageRect];

    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return croppedImage;
```

}